# Extract only year from ambiguous column in dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

[Data for Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktswh.png) I have a dataframe containing ambiguous types of dates. Some cells include only years, some include date and some include date and time. How can I extract only the year part from such a column?

I tried using

```
df$Year<- format(df$DoB,format="%Y")
df$Year <- df[year(df$DoB)]
```

And some more pieces but nothing gives the desired output. When I check the

```
typeof(df$DoB)

Output: character
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Please use `dput(df)` i.e. original data to understand the data `format` wouldnt work if your 'DoB' is not `Date` class

Comment: I ran the following command class(df$DoB) and it gives the output as character. But since the data is in various formats (Just the year, Date Time, Just the time), I cannot use as.Date() either. What am I missing over here?

Comment: You said `just the time`  if it have just the time, then what will be the year

Comment: My bad. Its just 2 formats: The year, MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS. I have added a Screenshot of the dataset for reference.

Comment: Try the solution with `parse_date`

Answer (score 1):

If years are the only values with four consecutive digits, you could try this quick and dirty approach.

```
df$Year <- gsub(pattern = ".*(\\d{4}).*", replacement = "\\1", x = df$DoB)
```

Comment: Thank you. This does work but I was looking for a cleaner approach either by using a simpler function / lubridate

Comment: @Phant5x you need to show some data for others to understand the format

Answer (score 1):

An option is `parse_date`

```
library(parsedate)
library(lubridate)
year(parse_date(v1))
[1] 2014 2009 2019
```

---

Or with `lubridate` alone

```
year(parse_date_time(v1, c("mdy_HM", "y")))
[1] 2014 2009 2019
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c("3/4/2014 10:44", "2009", "2/24/2019 14:06")
```

Answer (score 1):

Using regular expressions in `regmatches/regexpr`.

```
with(DF, regmatches(x, regexpr('\\d{4}', x)))
# [1] "2019" "2019" "2019" "2019" "2019" "2019" "2019" "2010" "2019" "2019" "2019" "2019"
# [13] "1999" "2019" "2019" "2019" "2019" "2019" "2019" "2019" "2009" "2009" "2019" "2019"
```

---

*Data*

```
DF <- structure(list(x = c("15/07/2019 13:35", "04/07/2019 04:35", 
"07/07/2019 16:35", "19/07/2019 22:35", "19/07/2019 01:35", "05/07/2019 22:35", 
"09/07/2019 10:35", "2010", "12/07/2019 22:35", "13/07/2019 19:35", 
"12/07/2019 01:35", "10/07/2019 07:35", "1999", "05/07/2019 01:35", 
"03/07/2019 07:35", "08/07/2019 13:35", "18/07/2019 04:35", "16/07/2019 10:35", 
"14/07/2019 16:35", "17/07/2019 07:35", "2009", "2009", "11/07/2019 04:35", 
"06/07/2019 19:35"), something = c(0.351949435425922, 0.738759625935927, 
0.569440030492842, 0.544267772696912, 0.84932046988979, 0.27733932598494, 
0.750392054906115, 0.18246348015964, 0.826719622127712, 0.599489526124671, 
0.0338777017313987, 0.50471409317106, 0.570326073328033, 0.71366912452504, 
0.423946351278573, 0.72098550782539, 0.257781937019899, 0.918342786142603, 
0.287502277176827, 0.938778957352042, 0.953107961220667, 0.143501925980672, 
0.666596594033763, 0.943008679896593)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-24L))
 
tail(DF)
#                   x something
# 19 14/07/2019 16:35 0.2875023
# 20 17/07/2019 07:35 0.9387790
# 21             2009 0.9531080
# 22             2009 0.1435019
# 23 11/07/2019 04:35 0.6665966
# 24 06/07/2019 19:35 0.9430087
```